# Swift JSON not parsing Data Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, youtube-data-api, swifty-json

I am trying to **parse data** from the YouTube Data API into a **swift string**. Therefore, I am using *Alamofire* as well as *SwiftyJSON*. However, SwiftyJSON does not parse anything and I get an error *"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"*.

### My API Call

```
YTDataService.fetchDetails(forVideo: videoId, parts: [VideoPart.statistics, VideoPart.contentDetails], onDone: {(details) in
                    // details is of Type JSON
                    let videoDuration = details["items"]["contentDetails"]["duration"].string! // not parsing
                    let videoViews = details["items"]["statistics"]["viewCount"].string! // not parsing

                    print(videoDuration, videoViews)
                })
            })
```

### The JSON Response from YouTube

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/UwkUogFGo4AZoBzZtd5t6Tj8wk0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/qsX1KSuT5vhpp29lsFl_1l6uvWE\"",
   "id": "Dkk9gvTmCXY",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT3M31S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "129895203",
    "likeCount": "3178074",
    "dislikeCount": "266720",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "230345"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

As you can see, I am correctly trying to parse the data - but for some reason, SwiftyJSON does not parse the data correctly.

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: items is can array and not a dictionary. You cannot get contentDetails from it directly.

Comment: Oh my god.... Definitely spent too much time on this  post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct :) Thanks @PGDev

Comment: Added the answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is an `array` and not a `dictionary`. You cannot get `contentDetails` from it directly.

Get the `first` element from `items` `array` and then fetch `contentDetails` and `statistics` from it. Then get `duration` and `viewCount` further.

```
YTDataService.fetchDetails(forVideo: videoId, parts: [VideoPart.statistics, VideoPart.contentDetails], onDone: {(details) in
    if let item = details["items"].array.first {
        let videoDuration = item["contentDetails"]["duration"].string
        let videoViews = item["statistics"]["viewCount"].string
        print(videoDuration, videoViews)
    }
})
```

`videoDuration` and `videoViews` will be fetched as `optionals`. Use `if-let` or *nil-coalescing* (`??`) operator to unwrap the values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deal with `items` as array

```
if let item = details["items"].array.first , let dur = item["contentDetails"]["duration"].string {
   print(dur)
}
```

Same for `viewCount`

```
if let item = details["items"].array.first , let videoCount = item["statistics"]["viewCount"].string {
   print(videoCount)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get value from an array so first get the first item from array then get one by one value from this item like bellow code

```
guard let item = details["items"].array.first else { return }
let videoDuration = item["statistics"]["viewCount"].stringValue
let videoViews = item["statistics"]["viewCount"].stringValue
```